How to handle state changes in View model?
I need to know what is the right way to make custom changes to model when Binding or Bindable var updates in UI. Specifically, here is my problem. I have my view model as follows:
enum ChosenControl {
   case none, option1, option2, option3
}

@Observable class CustomViewModel {
   var sliderVal: Float = 0.5
   var sliderMinVal: Float = 0.0
   var sliderMaxVal: Float = 1.0
   var chosenControl: ChosenControl = .none

   func chooseControl(_ controlOpt:ChosenControl) {
      sliderMinVal = getMinValForOpt(controlOpt)
      sliderVal =    getCurrentValForOpt(controlOpt)
      sliderMaxVal = getMaxValForOpt(controlOpt)
   }
}

I now create @Bindable from these three variables in ViewModel and hook it to slider in my SwiftUI view.
Slider(value: $customViewModel.sliderVal) { editing in
    print("Editing...")
}

My problem is I also want to perform custom actions in my model when sliderVal changes in UI (not otherwise, as sliderVal, sliderMinVal, sliderMaxVal can be changed programatically when user changes chosenControl through UI). What is the right way to do this?

You can define an interceptor-like property

onChange modifier is one way but it can only be done in SwiftUI view, not in the model. I want to know a cleaner way if possible.

In SwiftUI the View struct hierarchy is the view model and @State is for dynamic data, you'll have more success if you just use it this way instead of your own custom objects.

@malhal I created a simplified code but in reality if I keep slider values in @State object, there will be thousands of State vars in the view. I need to keep things modular.

UI State should be managed eith value types per Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state you can use computes properties, task, onChange. Observable as observarion tracking too. The “right” way is really subjective.

@DeepakSharma you are supposed to group related vars into a @State struct

You can define an interceptor-like property:
let sliderValInterceptor = Binding<Float>(
    get: { customViewModel.sliderVal },
    set: {
        customViewModel.sliderVal = $0
        /*  Do the extra work here  */
    }
)

Then use it where you need:
Slider(value: sliderValInterceptor) { editing in
    print("Editing...")
}

So setting the sliderValInterceptor will have extra effects that the original binding dont.

Will the slider get updated whenever customViewModel.sliderVal changes anywhere in the code? Also, how do we differentiate whether customViewModel.sliderVal was changed through slider or was updated programatically?

Yes, because CustomViewModel is Observable. You can use a simple flag or keep track of the extra work somewhere and compare when you need to.
